# React-native Animated api : undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _reactNative.Animated.value(0)')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I was following the code from react native documentation for using Animated API [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated)

I got an error while using this line

```
const scrollY = useRef( new Animated.value(0)).current;
```

**ERROR** :  `TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _reactNative.Animated.value(0)')`

I have imported Animated from

```
import { Animated } from "react-native";
```

I don't know what I have done wrong, I am using the same code from the documentation

Answer (score 1):

It's:

```
const scrollY = useRef( new Animated.Value(0)).current;
```

Not

```
const scrollY = useRef( new Animated.value(0)).current;
```

From `v` to uppercase `V`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I found a solution. Try the following code:

```
Animated.timing(scrollY,{
  toValue:
  duration:
  useNativeDriver: false
})
```